# Tikz: separating items based on line separation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am writing a document which will eventually be submitted with double line spacing (by using `\linespread{1.6}`). I am using including `tikz` images some of which are separated (they're fractals so showing different stages of construction). I would like to know whether or not it is possible to separente lines in a Tikzpicture based of the separation value for between the lines in text (so it changes when I change the value to 1.6).

*My Minimum Worked Example*:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Cantor set]
    \draw (0,0) -- (7,0) node[right] {$E_{0}$};
    \draw decorate{ (0,-.5) -- (7,-.5)} node[right] {$E_{1}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1) -- (7,-1)}} node[right] {$E_{2}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-1.5) -- (7,-1.5)}}} node[right] {$E_{3}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2) -- (7,-2)}}}} node[right] {$E_{4}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. A [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would be very useful, here. As your question stands, it is unclear how the different pictures for each stage of the fractals are separated in your case.

Comment: @marsupilam, is this better? Thanks you for the feedback.

Comment: Instead of a 0.5 (cm) spacing, use a macro or length which can be reset.  I'm have no idea how \linespread works, but you might try \baselineskip.  That is how I would emulated "double spacing".

Comment: It is better to post compilable code as the link explaining construction of minimal examples explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce it artificially but it would be not so robust unless you really include every possible case. Otherwise a simple parametrization is sufficient. But now you are officially warned against this usage :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\begin{document}

\linespread{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Cantor set]
    \draw (0,0) -- (7,0) node[right]  (z) {$E_{0}$};
    \draw decorate{ (0,-\baselineskip) -- (7,-\baselineskip)} node[right] {$E_{1}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2\baselineskip) -- (7,-2\baselineskip)}} node[right] {$E_{2}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-3\baselineskip) -- (7,-3\baselineskip)}}} node[right] {$E_{3}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-4\baselineskip) -- (7,-4\baselineskip)}}}} node[right] {$E_{4}$};
\node[anchor=north west, align=left, text width=4cm] at (z.north east) {
asd fasdf afgsdf sdfgs dfg dsfgsd sdfga afasd adfa adfasdf adfa a asdf
asd fasdf afgsdf sdfgs dfg dsfgsd sdfga afasd adfa 
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{3cm}

\linespread{1.6}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=Cantor set]
    \draw (0,0) -- (7,0) node[right]  (z) {$E_{0}$};
    \draw decorate{ (0,-\baselineskip) -- (7,-\baselineskip)} node[right] {$E_{1}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ (0,-2\baselineskip) -- (7,-2\baselineskip)}} node[right] {$E_{2}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-3\baselineskip) -- (7,-3\baselineskip)}}} node[right] {$E_{3}$};
    \draw decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,-4\baselineskip) -- (7,-4\baselineskip)}}}} node[right] {$E_{4}$};
\node[anchor=north west, align=left, text width=4cm] at (z.north east) {
asd fasdf afgsdf sdfgs dfg dsfgsd sdfga afasd adfa adfasdf adfa a asdf
asd fasdf afgsdf sdfgs dfg dsfgsd sdfga afasd adfa adfasdf adfa
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]